# ADO.NET Data Services and eager loading?

Tags: c#, service, sharepoint-2010, ado.net

I'm using sharepoint 2010 listdata.svc service who uses ADO.NET Data Services. I'm wondering if it's possible to do eager loading with this service without writing own DTO objects.